# template of variadic template: parameter pack expects a type template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

```
template <typename T, template <typename T, typename... Targs> class C>
void print_(const C<T,Targs>& arg, std::stringstream& ss)
{
    std::for_each(arg.begin(), arg.end(), [&ss](const T& var) { ss << var; });
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
   std::stringstream ss;
   print_(vec,ss);
}
```

> main.cpp(8): error C2065: 'Targs': undeclared identifier
> main.cpp(8): error C3544: 'Targs': parameter pack expects a type template

Comment: can someone pls help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names that are part of a template parameters list introduced by a template template parameter are valid only within that list.
In other terms, something like this is legal:

```
template<template<typename T, T> class U>
struct S {};
```

And you can use it as it follows:

```
template<typename T, T>
struct A {};

template<template<typename T, T> class U>
struct B {};

int main() {
    B<A> b;
}
```

This isn't valid code instead:

```
template <typename T, template <typename T, typename... Targs> class C>
void print_(const C<T,Targs> &, std::stringstream &);
```

`Targs` is no longer a valid name after the first `>` symbol (the one that follows immediately `Targs` itself).
The compiler keeps saying it to you quite clearly: *undeclared identifier*.

---

That being said, in your question there isn't an actual question, so I don't know what you expect from an answer but to tell you why that's an error.

Answer (score 0):

this worked!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
template <typename T, template <typename T, typename... > class C, class... Args>
void print_(std::stringstream& ss, const C<T,Args...>& arg)
{
    std::for_each(arg.begin(), arg.end(), [&ss](const T& var) { ss << var << ":"; });
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
   std::stringstream ss;
   print_(ss, vec);
   cout << ss.str();
}
```